# How to add a new modal type with ajax_register.module?

Tags: php, drupal

I am working on a Drupal project, which uses ajax_register.module. Register, login and forgot password works well. However, I have a problem. When a user registers with Facebook, the given user does not necessarily have an email for his Facebook user. When this is the case, I would like to ask the user for his or her email address in a separate modal window. For this purpose, I would like to add a new type of modal window, containing an input for the email address and show it.

This is the behavior I would like to achieve:
- user clicks on register/login
- on the modal dialog, user clicks on the Facebook button
- if the Facebook user of the user does not exist, then I would like to store a JSON in `$_SESSION["register"]`
- when the main page reloads, if `$_SESSION["register"]` exists, I would like to open a modal window asking for the email address
- when the user fills the email address and submits the form, on server I would like to handle the registration process, knowing the email address and the other data

Is there a way to add a new modal window type to ajax_register.module?

Comment: Maybe it would be better, if you change the register/login form (using hook_form_alter) and add new required field for email?

Comment: @ErmineSoft, my case is applicable when someone does not want to register with Facebook and for this specific reason the user clicks on the register with Facebook button. In this case data is gathered from Facebook and the user will be registered through Facebook. However, there is a special case when the user's email address does not have an email. In this case registration with Facebook fails. Since this involves redirect to Facebook and then redirect back to the home page, adding fields are not options. I would like to have a separate modal for this case.

Comment: I can solve my problem with jQuery hacks, however, I would prefer to do this elegantly. I was checking out the module, but I have not found useful info about how to add a new modal. The page of https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_register left me clueless about unhacky solutions for my problem.

Comment: I think you can achieve this with ctools modal + hook into ajax_register form process.